# Is it possible to create a variadic macro which generates a forwarding function?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

*I'm pretty sure the answer to this question is a "no" but I would be very glad to be proven wrong*

Say I have a variadic template function

```
template <typename... Args>
void log(Args&&... args) { ... }
```

...and I also have macros to generate concrete logging functions. Like:

```
#define LOG_2(fname, arg0_type, arg0_name, arg1_type, arg1_name) \
  void fname(arg0_type arg0_name, arg1_type arg1_name) { \
    log(std::forward<arg0_type>(arg0_name), std::forward<arg1_type>(arg1_name)); }
```

Macros named `LOG_0` to `LOG_10` with similar code also exist.

I use them to generate special logging functions which serve two purposes. First they give strong types to the arguments, and second they give them names, which with code-completion cam be used as hints. Example:

```
LOG_2(progress_log, const char*, msg, float, part)
...
progress_log("Loading: ", complete/total);
```

Then besides the strong typing of the args, I get the following nice code completion hint:

[image: code completion hint]

So, is it possible to drop the explicit arity in the macros and write something which has the exact same effect but uses variadic macros? ...and also isn't macro which uses a counter to call one of the underlying arity-macros by concatenating the appropriate number with `LOG_`.

I am aware I can count the arguments but most code-completion tools utterly fail to expand counting macros, especially if the possible argument count is big (like 10). Thus the code-completion effect gets lost. And if I would be willing to drop the code-completion hint effect, then I'd rather go with a something like `LOG_FUN(progress_log, void(const char*, float))` which can also be used to generate compilation errors, but can have no argument names as hints

Comment: Use of macros in this came seems like a degradation.

Comment: Well, my case isn't *exactly* this. The macro does need to generate more. But I did list the main pros: explicit names and types, and code-completion hints

Comment: @aschepler yes, thank you :)

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just write `progress_log` manually. Unless you have hundreds of logging functions, which sounds like a serious design flaw, typing it out ten times and be done forever sounds pretty fine. It's not like the macro saves much typing anyways

Comment: For my actual case the macro generates much more than the forwarding function. However the need for explicit arity is for it only. That's why I made up this logging example which minimally shows the problem - the arity, the forwarding function, and its benefits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/libs/preprocessor/) library is made for just this sort of case when you really want to do something fancy with preprocessor macros.  It can get a bit ugly, though.

```
#include <boost/preprocessor/variadic/to_seq.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/seq/for_each_i.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/if.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/arithmetic.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/punctuation.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/logical.hpp>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Args>
void log(Args&&...) {}

#define DEF_LOG_COMMA_BEFORE_PAIR(i) \
  BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(BOOST_PP_AND(i, BOOST_PP_NOT(BOOST_PP_MOD(i,2))))

#define DEF_LOG_EXPAND_PARAM(r, data, i, elem) \
  DEF_LOG_COMMA_BEFORE_PAIR(i) elem

#define DEF_LOG_EXPAND_CALL(r, data, i, elem) \
  DEF_LOG_COMMA_BEFORE_PAIR(i) \
  BOOST_PP_IF( BOOST_PP_MOD(i,2), \
    (elem), \
    std::forward<elem> )

#define DEF_LOG_FUNC(name, ...) \
  inline void name( \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(DEF_LOG_EXPAND_PARAM, ~, \
      BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  ) { log( \
    BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I(DEF_LOG_EXPAND_CALL, ~, \
      BOOST_PP_VARIADIC_TO_SEQ(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  ); }

DEF_LOG_FUNC(progress_log, const char*, msg, float, part)

int main() {
    progress_log("Progress", 0.25);
}
```

To pull this apart, first look at the `DEF_LOG_COMMA_BEFORE_PAIR` macro.  It's just a helper that expands to a comma if the argument `i` is an even number other than zero, and expands to nothing otherwise.  By putting it before the result of transforming one vararg parameter, we get a comma every other item.  (After might seem more natural, but it would be a little more complicated to exclude a comma after the last term than this way of excluding the comma before the first item.)  Note [`BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/comma_if.html) is used to avoid expanding to a comma too early, which would confuse the other Boost macros.

Jumping down to the definition of the main macro `DEF_LOG_FUNC`, you'll see it uses [`BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/seq_for_each_i.html) twice.  This is a tool which applies a supplied macro to each term from a passed sequence of arguments.  The macro given must accept four arguments:

- `r`: used when you need multiple levels of preprocessor loops
- `data`: a sequence of tokens passed directly through `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I` to each invocation of the macro
- `i`: the zero-based index of the sequence element
- `elem`: the actual sequence element

Neither of our macros actually needs `data`, so we just pass `~` as a dummy token to both `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I` uses.  The two helper macros we pass to `BOOST_PP_SEQ_FOR_EACH_I` are `DEF_LOG_EXPAND_PARAM` for building the function parameter list and `DEF_LOG_EXPAND_CALL` for building the argument list to the actual `log` function.  `DEF_LOG_EXPAND_PARAM` doesn't need to do anything but add commas, using that `DEF_LOG_COMMA_BEFORE_PAIR` helper.  `DEF_LOG_EXPAND_CALL` needs to do different things to even and odd arguments, so in addition to the `DEF_LOG_COMMA_BEFORE_PAIR` tool again, it uses [`BOOST_PP_IF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/if.html) to transform even (type) arguments to `std::forward<elem>` and odd (parameter) arguments to `(elem)`.

So as desired, the preprocessor replaces

```
DEF_LOG_FUNC(progress_log, const char*, msg, float, part)
```

as

```
inline void progress_log(
    const char* msg , float part
) { log(
    std::forward<const char*> (msg) , std::forward<float> (part)
); }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. IntelliSense in VS2013 through 2017 expands it well, too (unlike the counting macros)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some *tags* instead. If you need to provide hint for special cases then you can write some explicit specializations:

```
enum Category{normal, progress};

template<Category category = normal, typename... Args>
void log(Args... args) { ... }

template<>
void log<progress, char const *, float>(char const *, float) { ... }

// typing this will show generic and specialized variant hints in VS2017
log<progress>("Loading: ", complete/total);
```